# Ansible test to check file exists

Tags: ansible

Based on this document I am trying to check the `/etc/hosts` file exists. but Ansible giving

`The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '/'`

error message

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths

```
- debug:
    msg: "host file already exists"
  when: /etc/hosts is exists
```

What is the right way of using this testing condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The section of the documentation to which you've linked is probably
not what you want -- that is only for testing paths *on the
controller* (that is, the host on which Ansible is running), rather
than the target host(s) of your play.

If that is what you want, you need to fix the syntax of your `when`
expression. The examples to which you've linked are all of the form
`<variable> is <test>`, so you would write something like:

```
- debug:
    msg: "host file already exists"
  when: etchosts is exists
  vars:
    etchosts: "/etc/hosts"
```

Here we define a string variable named `etchosts` containing our path.
In the above example we've defined it at the task level, but this
could also be defined at the play level, as a group_ or host_var, via
`set_fact`, etc.

---

To test for a file on a target host, use the `stat` module:

```
- name: check for /etc/hosts
  stat:
    path: /etc/hosts
  register: etchosts
```

We [register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the result in a variable named `etchosts` so that we can use it in a subsequent task. For example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "/etc/hosts exists"
  when: etchosts.stat.exists

- debug:
    msg: "/etc/hosts does not exist"
  when: not etchosts.stat.exists
```